# loop through table row and get each value in row - find error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I have a simple table that I am trying to loop through and get the value of each cell in each row if it has `<td>s`.

But I get an error saying `find` does not exist, and yes jquery is added. Can you please help. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = $('table tr:has(td)');
    $.each(x, function (i, v) {

        alert(
        v.find('td').eq(0).text()); + " ----" + v.find('td').eq(1).find('option:selected').val(););
    });

});

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="no">no</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="no">no</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="no">no</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="no">no</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="yes">yes</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="no">no</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In this line: `v.find('td').eq(0).text()); + " ----" +` the semi-colon indicates that it's the end of the statement, which means the attempt at string concatenation will throw a Javascript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v` is the element on the DOM, so you need to wrap it into the `$` function in order to chain another jQuery method : `$(v).find(...)`

note: you could also write `$(this).find(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tr:has(td)').each(function (tr) {
        $('td', tr).each(function (td) {
          alert($(td).text());
        });
    });
});
```